# Как запустить пакет тестов NIST?

Tags: c, математика, случайные-числа, криптография

Немного глупый вопрос ,но как запустить пакет тестов NIST(вариация с оф. сайта)? Системы : либо Linux mint 19.1(x64) ,либо  Windows 10(x64). Если есть возможность ,то ,пожалуйста,опишите процесс запуска и работы с пакетом как можно подробнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала следует распаковать архив. После этого нужно перейти в распакованный архив,открыть раздел в нем с шестью папками,открыть эту директорию в терминале и запустить команду make. При необходимости недостающие библиотеки для сборки из makefile можно установить через apt. После этого появится в выше означенной директории файл assess. Для дальнейшей работу стоит следовать инструкциям в документации с оф. сайта NIST.(это для работы на Linux)